# Using Image Map within a div with CSS rules

Tags: css, html, imagemap

I have created a div with a image I'm using with Image Map.

```
<div id="image"> 
<img src="image.png" usemap="imagemap"> 
</div>
```

Css:

```
#image {   float: right; }
```

But when I use the CSS with the Image Map, it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the map and the image or an example so that we can test it, or do you have a site with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using

```
<div id="image" align="right"> 
<img src="image.png" usemap="imagemap"> 
</div>
```

and dropped the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent [Tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/programming-and-development/how-do-i-use-css-to-create-an-image-map-on-my-web-site/660) on image maps hope this can help explain the process a little better.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty decent [Tutorial](http://www.neopets.com/~Kacizilla) here, although the mapping is limited to rectangles.